# how to integrate this function by general technique

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

> $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=?$    where
>
> $f(x)= \begin{cases}0\qquad&0\le x<1/2 \\1/2\qquad&x=1/2\\0\qquad&1/2<x\le1\end{cases}
> $

since f is discontinuous only at one point then I know it is integrable and by calculating infimum of $U(P,f)$ and supremum of $L(P,f)$ where P is a partition ,I see that 0 is integral.But how to calculate it by general technique like $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\left[g(x)\right]_0^1$

Comment: Works with $g(x)=0$

Comment: but f(x) is 1/2 at x=1/2

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus is valid only for continuous functions.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can i neglect the point 1/2 since f is discontinuous only one point

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate as follows:
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^{1/2}0dx+\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{\frac12-\epsilon}^{\frac12+\epsilon} \frac12dx+\int_{1/2}^1 0dx=0+\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \epsilon+0=0.$$

Comment: what is the limit on the integral good for? The function is =/ 0 on a closed interval (hence compact) and as a constant Riemann integrable.